# Hibernate Update does Not Update Anything

Tags: hibernate, transactions

In theory, this code should set the new lock status to the users and get that written to the database:

```
transaction = sess.beginTransaction();
String hql = "update User set locked=:newLockStatus where principalId in (:userIds)";
Query query = sess.createQuery(hql);
query.setBoolean("newLockStatus", locked);
query.setParameterList("userIds", userIdList);
query.executeUpdate();
transaction.commit();
```

When I run this code, I don't get an error or an exception or anything... but when I read the status of these users afterwards, I see that their lock status is unchanged. If I connect directly to the database, I see the same thing. I interpret that as meaning that I'm not having a cache synchronization issue, but really that there is either:

- a problem in the query
- a bug in Hibernate such that the update doesn't get reflected

Anyone knows?

**EDIT**:
Here is the log output (with lots of noise removed) as requested:

```
DEBUG org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl - opened session at timestamp: 12676941899
TRACE o.h.e.def.DefaultLoadEventListener - loading entity: [User#100012]
TRACE o.h.e.def.DefaultLoadEventListener - attempting to resolve: [User#100012]
TRACE o.h.e.def.DefaultLoadEventListener - object not resolved in any cache: [User#100012]
TRACE o.h.p.entity.AbstractEntityPersister - Fetching entity: [User#100012]
DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - loading entity: [User#100012]
DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)
DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager - opening JDBC connection
TRACE o.h.c.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - total checked-out connections: 0
TRACE o.h.c.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - using pooled JDBC connection, pool size: 0
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select user0_.principalId as principa2_1_0_, user0_.displayName as displayN3_1_0_, user0_.locked as locked1_0_, user0_.XYZ as XYZ5_1_0_, user0_.ABC as ABC6_1_0_, user0_.DEF as DEF1_0_ from PRINCIPAL user0_ where user0_.principalId=? and user0_.TYPE='USER'
Hibernate: select user0_.principalId as principa2_1_0_, user0_.displayName as displayN3_1_0_, user0_.locked as locked1_0_, user0_.XYZ as XYZ5_1_0_, user0_.ABC as ABC6_1_0_, user0_.DEF as DEF1_0_ from PRINCIPAL user0_ where user0_.principalId=? and user0_.TYPE='USER'
TRACE org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - preparing statement
TRACE org.hibernate.type.StringType - binding '100012' to parameter: 1
DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - about to open ResultSet (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)
TRACE org.hibernate.loader.Loader - processing result set
DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - result set row: 0
DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - result row: EntityKey[User#100012]
TRACE org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Initializing object from ResultSet: [User#100012]
TRACE o.h.p.entity.AbstractEntityPersister - Hydrating entity: [User#100012]
TRACE org.hibernate.type.StringType - returning 'MURALI KRISHNA  PRASAD YELESWARAPU' as column: displayN3_1_0_
TRACE org.hibernate.type.BooleanType - returning 'false' as column: locked1_0_
DEBUG org.hibernate.type.EnumType - Returning 'DEF' as column DEF1_0_
TRACE org.hibernate.loader.Loader - done processing result set (1 rows)
DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - about to close ResultSet (open ResultSets: 1, globally: 1)
DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - about to close PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 1, globally: 1)
TRACE org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - closing statement
TRACE org.hibernate.loader.Loader - total objects hydrated: 1
DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.TwoPhaseLoad - resolving associations for [User#100012]
TRACE o.h.engine.loading.LoadContexts - creating collection wrapper:[User.roles#100012]
DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.TwoPhaseLoad - done materializing entity [User#100012]
DEBUG o.h.e.StatefulPersistenceContext - initializing non-lazy collections
DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - done entity load
TRACE org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext - after autocommit
DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager - aggressively releasing JDBC connection
DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager - releasing JDBC connection [ (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0) (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)]
TRACE o.h.c.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - returning connection to pool, pool size: 1
DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager - opening JDBC connection
TRACE o.h.c.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - total checked-out connections: 0
TRACE o.h.c.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - using pooled JDBC connection, pool size: 0
TRACE o.h.e.def.DefaultLoadEventListener - loading entity: [User#100000]
TRACE o.h.e.def.DefaultLoadEventListener - attempting to resolve: [User#100000]
TRACE o.h.e.def.DefaultLoadEventListener - object not resolved in any cache: [User#100000]
TRACE o.h.p.entity.AbstractEntityPersister - Fetching entity: [User#100000]
DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - loading entity: [User#100000]
DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select user0_.principalId as principa2_1_0_, user0_.displayName as displayN3_1_0_, user0_.locked as locked1_0_, user0_.XYZ as XYZ5_1_0_, user0_.ABC as ABC6_1_0_, user0_.DEF as DEF1_0_ from PRINCIPAL user0_ where user0_.principalId=? and user0_.TYPE='USER'
Hibernate: select user0_.principalId as principa2_1_0_, user0_.displayName as displayN3_1_0_, user0_.locked as locked1_0_, user0_.XYZ as XYZ5_1_0_, user0_.ABC as ABC6_1_0_, user0_.DEF as DEF1_0_ from PRINCIPAL user0_ where user0_.principalId=? and user0_.TYPE='USER'
TRACE org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - preparing statement
TRACE org.hibernate.type.StringType - binding '100000' to parameter: 1
DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - about to open ResultSet (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)
TRACE org.hibernate.loader.Loader - processing result set
DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - result set row: 0
DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - result row: EntityKey[User#100000]
TRACE org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Initializing object from ResultSet: [User#100000]
TRACE o.h.p.entity.AbstractEntityPersister - Hydrating entity: [User#100000]
TRACE org.hibernate.type.StringType - returning 'SHAMLAL AGGARWAL' as column: displayN3_1_0_
TRACE org.hibernate.type.BooleanType - returning 'false' as column: locked1_0_
DEBUG org.hibernate.type.EnumType - Returning 'DEF' as column DEF1_0_
TRACE org.hibernate.loader.Loader - done processing result set (1 rows)
DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - about to close ResultSet (open ResultSets: 1, globally: 1)
DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - about to close PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 1, globally: 1)
TRACE org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - closing statement
TRACE org.hibernate.loader.Loader - total objects hydrated: 1
DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.TwoPhaseLoad - resolving associations for [User#100000]
TRACE o.h.engine.loading.LoadContexts - creating collection wrapper:[User.roles#100000]
DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.TwoPhaseLoad - done materializing entity [User#100000]
DEBUG o.h.e.StatefulPersistenceContext - initializing non-lazy collections
DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - done entity load
TRACE org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext - after autocommit
DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager - aggressively releasing JDBC connection
DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager - releasing JDBC connection [ (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0) (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)]
TRACE o.h.c.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - returning connection to pool, pool size: 1
DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager - opening JDBC connection
TRACE o.h.c.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - total checked-out connections: 0
TRACE o.h.c.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - using pooled JDBC connection, pool size: 0
DEBUG o.h.transaction.JDBCTransaction - begin
DEBUG o.h.transaction.JDBCTransaction - current autocommit status: false
TRACE org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext - after transaction begin
TRACE o.h.engine.query.QueryPlanCache - unable to locate HQL query plan in cache; generating (update User set locked = :newLockStatus where principalId in (:userIds))
DEBUG o.h.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl - parse() - HQL: update User set locked = :newLockStatus where principalId in (:userIds)
DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.ast.AST - --- HQL AST ---
 \-[UPDATE] 'update'
    +-[FROM] 'FROM'
    |  \-[RANGE] 'RANGE'
    |     \-[DOT] '.'
    |        +-[DOT] '.'
    |        |  +-[DOT] '.'
    |        |  |  +-[DOT] '.'
    |        |  |  |  +-[DOT] '.'
    |        |  |  |  |  +-[DOT] '.'
    |        |  |  |  |  |  +-[IDENT] 'X'
    |        |  |  |  |  |  \-[IDENT] 'X'
    |        |  |  |  |  \-[IDENT] 'X'
    |        |  |  |  \-[IDENT] 'X'
    |        |  |  \-[IDENT] 'X'
    |        |  \-[IDENT] 'X'
    |        \-[IDENT] 'User'
    +-[SET] 'set'
    |  \-[EQ] '='
    |     +-[IDENT] 'locked'
    |     \-[COLON] ':'
    |        \-[IDENT] 'newLockStatus'
    \-[WHERE] 'where'
       \-[IN] 'in'
          +-[IDENT] 'principalId'
          \-[IN_LIST] 'inList'
             \-[COLON] ':'
                \-[IDENT] 'userIds'

DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter - throwQueryException() : no errors
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -> statement (update [UPDATE])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - ---> updateStatement (update [UPDATE])
DEBUG o.h.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker - update << begin [level=1, statement=update]
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -----> fromClause (FROM [FROM])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -------> fromElementList (RANGE [RANGE])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - ---------> fromElement (RANGE [RANGE])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -----------> path (. [DOT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -------------> path (. [DOT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - ---------------> path (. [DOT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -----------------> path (. [DOT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -------------------> path (. [DOT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - ---------------------> path (. [DOT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -----------------------> path (X [IDENT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -------------------------> identifier (X [IDENT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <------------------------- identifier
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <----------------------- path
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -----------------------> identifier (X [IDENT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <----------------------- identifier
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <--------------------- path
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - ---------------------> identifier (X [IDENT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <--------------------- identifier
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <------------------- path
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -------------------> identifier (X [IDENT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <------------------- identifier
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <----------------- path
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -----------------> identifier (X [IDENT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <----------------- identifier
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <--------------- path
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - ---------------> identifier (X [IDENT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <--------------- identifier
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <------------- path
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -------------> identifier (User [IDENT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <------------- identifier
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <----------- path
DEBUG o.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromElement - FromClause{level=1} :  User (no alias) -> user0_
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <--------- fromElement
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <------- fromElementList
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <----- fromClause
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -----> setClause (set [SET])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -------> assignment (= [EQ])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - ---------> propertyRef (locked [IDENT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -----------> identifier (locked [IDENT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <----------- identifier
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - attempting to resolve property [locked] as a non-qualified ref
DEBUG o.h.hql.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode - Resolved :  {synthetic-alias} -> {synthetic-alias}
TRACE o.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromElement - handling property dereference [User (null) -> locked (class)]
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <--------- propertyRef
DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.DotNode - getDataType() : locked -> org.hibernate.type.BooleanType@1fe4169
TRACE o.h.hql.ast.tree.FromElementType - Using non-qualified column reference [locked -> ([locked])]
DEBUG o.h.hql.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode - Resolved :  {synthetic-alias}.locked -> locked
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - ---------> newValue (: [COLON])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -----------> expr (: [COLON])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -------------> parameter (: [COLON])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - ---------------> identifier (newLockStatus [IDENT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <--------------- identifier
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <------------- parameter
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <----------- expr
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <--------- newValue
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <------- assignment
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <----- setClause
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -----> whereClause (where [WHERE])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -------> logicalExpr (in [IN])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - ---------> comparisonExpr (in [IN])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -----------> exprOrSubquery (principalId [IDENT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -------------> expr (principalId [IDENT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - ---------------> addrExpr (principalId [IDENT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -----------------> identifier (principalId [IDENT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <----------------- identifier
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - attempting to resolve property [principalId] as a non-qualified ref
DEBUG o.h.hql.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode - Resolved :  {synthetic-alias} -> {synthetic-alias}
TRACE o.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromElement - handling property dereference [User (null) -> principalId (class)]
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <--------------- addrExpr
DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.DotNode - getDataType() : principalId -> org.hibernate.type.StringType@f42160
TRACE o.h.hql.ast.tree.FromElementType - Using non-qualified column reference [principalId -> ([principalId])]
DEBUG o.h.hql.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode - Resolved :  {synthetic-alias}.principalId -> principalId
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <------------- expr
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <----------- exprOrSubquery
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -----------> inRhs (inList [IN_LIST])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -------------> expr (: [COLON])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - ---------------> parameter (: [COLON])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -----------------> identifier (userIds [IDENT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <----------------- identifier
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <--------------- parameter
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <------------- expr
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <----------- inRhs
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <--------- comparisonExpr
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <------- logicalExpr
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <----- whereClause
DEBUG o.h.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker - update : finishing up [level=1, statement=update]
DEBUG o.h.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker - update >> end [level=1, statement=update]
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <--- updateStatement
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <- statement
DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.ast.AST - --- SQL AST ---
 \-[UPDATE] UpdateStatement: 'update'  querySpaces (PRINCIPAL)
    +-[FROM] FromClause: 'FROM' FromClause{level=1, fromElementCounter=1, fromElements=1, fromElementByClassAlias=[], fromElementByTableAlias=[user0_], fromElementsByPath=[], collectionJoinFromElementsByPath=[], impliedElements=[]}
    |  \-[FROM_FRAGMENT] FromElement: 'PRINCIPAL' FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,not a fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=null,role=null,tableName=PRINCIPAL,tableAlias=user0_,origin=null,colums={,className=User}}
    +-[SET] SqlNode: 'set'
    |  \-[EQ] BinaryLogicOperatorNode: '='
    |     +-[DOT] DotNode: 'locked'
    |     |  +-[IDENT] IdentNode: '{synthetic-alias}'
    |     |  \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'locked'
    |     \-[NAMED_PARAM] ParameterNode: '?' {name=newLockStatus, expectedType=org.hibernate.type.BooleanType@1fe4169}
    \-[WHERE] SqlNode: 'where'
       \-[AND] SqlNode: '{and}'
          +-[SQL_TOKEN] SqlFragment: 'TYPE='USER''
          \-[IN] InLogicOperatorNode: 'in'
             +-[DOT] DotNode: 'principalId'
             |  +-[IDENT] IdentNode: '{synthetic-alias}'
             |  \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'principalId'
             \-[IN_LIST] SqlNode: 'inList'
                \-[NAMED_PARAM] ParameterNode: '?' {name=userIds, expectedType=org.hibernate.type.StringType@f42160}

DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter - throwQueryException() : no errors
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - -> statement (update [UPDATE])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - ---> updateStatement (update [UPDATE])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - -----> fromTable (PRINCIPAL [FROM_FRAGMENT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - <----- fromTable
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - -----> setClause (set [SET])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - -------> comparisonExpr (= [EQ])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - ---------> binaryComparisonExpression (= [EQ])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - -----------> expr (locked [DOT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - -------------> simpleExpr (locked [DOT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - ---------------> addrExpr (locked [DOT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - <--------------- addrExpr
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - <------------- simpleExpr
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - <----------- expr
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - -----------> expr (? [NAMED_PARAM])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - -------------> simpleExpr (? [NAMED_PARAM])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - ---------------> parameter (? [NAMED_PARAM])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - <--------------- parameter
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - <------------- simpleExpr
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - <----------- expr
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - <--------- binaryComparisonExpression
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - <------- comparisonExpr
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - <----- setClause
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - -----> whereClause (where [WHERE])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - -------> whereClauseExpr ({and} [AND])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - ---------> booleanExpr ({and} [AND])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - -----------> booleanOp ({and} [AND])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - -------------> booleanExpr (TYPE='USER' [SQL_TOKEN])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - <------------- booleanExpr
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - -------------> booleanExpr (in [IN])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - ---------------> comparisonExpr (in [IN])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - -----------------> exoticComparisonExpression (in [IN])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - -------------------> expr (principalId [DOT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - ---------------------> simpleExpr (principalId [DOT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - -----------------------> addrExpr (principalId [DOT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - <----------------------- addrExpr
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - <--------------------- simpleExpr
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - <------------------- expr
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - -------------------> inList (inList [IN_LIST])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - ---------------------> simpleExprList (? [NAMED_PARAM])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - -----------------------> simpleExpr (? [NAMED_PARAM])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - -------------------------> parameter (? [NAMED_PARAM])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - <------------------------- parameter
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - <----------------------- simpleExpr
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - <--------------------- simpleExprList
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - <------------------- inList
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - <----------------- exoticComparisonExpression
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - <--------------- comparisonExpr
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - <------------- booleanExpr
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - <----------- booleanOp
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - <--------- booleanExpr
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - <------- whereClauseExpr
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - <----- whereClause
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - <--- updateStatement
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.SqlGenerator - <- statement
DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter - throwQueryException() : no errors
TRACE o.h.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan - HQL param location recognition took 0 mills (update User set locked = :newLockStatus where principalId in (:userIds))
TRACE o.h.engine.query.QueryPlanCache - unable to locate HQL query plan in cache; generating (update User set locked = :newLockStatus where principalId in (:userIds0_, :userIds1_))
DEBUG o.h.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl - parse() - HQL: update User set locked = :newLockStatus where principalId in (:userIds0_, :userIds1_)
DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.ast.AST - --- HQL AST ---
 \-[UPDATE] 'update'
    +-[FROM] 'FROM'
    |  \-[RANGE] 'RANGE'
    |     \-[DOT] '.'
    |        +-[DOT] '.'
    |        |  +-[DOT] '.'
    |        |  |  +-[DOT] '.'
    |        |  |  |  +-[DOT] '.'
    |        |  |  |  |  +-[DOT] '.'
    |        |  |  |  |  |  +-[IDENT] 'X'
    |        |  |  |  |  |  \-[IDENT] 'X'
    |        |  |  |  |  \-[IDENT] 'X'
    |        |  |  |  \-[IDENT] 'X'
    |        |  |  \-[IDENT] 'X'
    |        |  \-[IDENT] 'X'
    |        \-[IDENT] 'User'
    +-[SET] 'set'
    |  \-[EQ] '='
    |     +-[IDENT] 'locked'
    |     \-[COLON] ':'
    |        \-[IDENT] 'newLockStatus'
    \-[WHERE] 'where'
       \-[IN] 'in'
          +-[IDENT] 'principalId'
          \-[IN_LIST] 'inList'
             +-[COLON] ':'
             |  \-[IDENT] 'userIds0_'
             \-[COLON] ':'
                \-[IDENT] 'userIds1_'

DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter - throwQueryException() : no errors
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -> statement (update [UPDATE])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - ---> updateStatement (update [UPDATE])
DEBUG o.h.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker - update << begin [level=1, statement=update]
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -----> fromClause (FROM [FROM])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -------> fromElementList (RANGE [RANGE])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - ---------> fromElement (RANGE [RANGE])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -----------> path (. [DOT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -------------> path (. [DOT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - ---------------> path (. [DOT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -----------------> path (. [DOT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -------------------> path (. [DOT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - ---------------------> path (. [DOT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -----------------------> path (X [IDENT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -------------------------> identifier (X [IDENT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <------------------------- identifier
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <----------------------- path
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -----------------------> identifier (X [IDENT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <----------------------- identifier
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <--------------------- path
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - ---------------------> identifier (X [IDENT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <--------------------- identifier
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <------------------- path
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -------------------> identifier (X [IDENT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <------------------- identifier
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <----------------- path
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -----------------> identifier (X [IDENT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <----------------- identifier
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <--------------- path
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - ---------------> identifier (X [IDENT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <--------------- identifier
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <------------- path
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -------------> identifier (User [IDENT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <------------- identifier
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <----------- path
DEBUG o.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromElement - FromClause{level=1} :  User (no alias) -> user0_
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <--------- fromElement
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <------- fromElementList
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <----- fromClause
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -----> setClause (set [SET])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -------> assignment (= [EQ])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - ---------> propertyRef (locked [IDENT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -----------> identifier (locked [IDENT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <----------- identifier
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - attempting to resolve property [locked] as a non-qualified ref
DEBUG o.h.hql.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode - Resolved :  {synthetic-alias} -> {synthetic-alias}
TRACE o.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromElement - handling property dereference [User (null) -> locked (class)]
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <--------- propertyRef
DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.DotNode - getDataType() : locked -> org.hibernate.type.BooleanType@1fe4169
TRACE o.h.hql.ast.tree.FromElementType - Using non-qualified column reference [locked -> ([locked])]
DEBUG o.h.hql.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode - Resolved :  {synthetic-alias}.locked -> locked
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - ---------> newValue (: [COLON])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -----------> expr (: [COLON])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -------------> parameter (: [COLON])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - ---------------> identifier (newLockStatus [IDENT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <--------------- identifier
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <------------- parameter
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <----------- expr
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <--------- newValue
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <------- assignment
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <----- setClause
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -----> whereClause (where [WHERE])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -------> logicalExpr (in [IN])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - ---------> comparisonExpr (in [IN])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -----------> exprOrSubquery (principalId [IDENT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -------------> expr (principalId [IDENT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - ---------------> addrExpr (principalId [IDENT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - -----------------> identifier (principalId [IDENT])
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - <----------------- identifier
TRACE org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker - attempting to resolve property [principalId] as a non-qualified ref
D
```

Comment: `executeUdpate()` returns the number of entities that were updated... what value does it return for you?

Comment: We're sending 2 user Ids, and `excuteUpdate` returns 2

Comment: That query is ok, I have something almost identical somewhere in my own code. Please set hibernate.show_sql to true in your Hibernate config file and check how the actual SQL looks like. It is hard to say anything more without seeing mapping file and User entity

Comment: Could you please add the hibernate configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you call sess.flush() and sess.close()?

Comment: Sorry about my previous comment. We had tried `flush` ing alone, and that didn't solve the problem. But `flush` + `close` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to have a Version column? When having a Version column (named X with current value of Y), Hibernate adds "SET X = Y + 1 WHERE X = Y". It may be the reason why you record isn't updated because it doesn't match the condition.
I recommend turning the log on, so you can see the actual Update statement Hibernate generates.

Hope it helps.

Comment: We don't have versioning enabled